# the eigen vectors of A corresponding to the eigenvalue -1

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that a $3×3$ matrix $A$ has eigenvalue $-1$. If the matrix $A+I$ is equal to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
then the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ are in the form

(A) \begin{pmatrix}
2t\\
0\\
t
\end{pmatrix}

(B) \begin{pmatrix}
2t\\
s\\
t
\end{pmatrix}

(C) \begin{pmatrix}
t\\
0\\
-2t
\end{pmatrix}

(D) \begin{pmatrix}
t\\
s\\
2t
\end{pmatrix}

In this case $A= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -2\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}$

Assuming $X=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}$
and computing $AX=-X$ gives the condition $a=2c$, and thus answer should be (B). I am confused about (A)

Comment: What exactly is your confusion? Those in (A) are eigenvectors, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-2\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2c\\-b\\-c\end{pmatrix}=-x\implies x=\begin{pmatrix}2c\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$

And notice that this is true *for any arbitrary $b$*. Option (A) is wrong because it forces $b$ to equal $0$, when in reality it can take on any value. Option (B) is correct because it has the relationship $a=2c$ but it also allows $b$ to be anything.